# Mina Sidekiq Queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, mina, sidekiq-monitor

I'm deploying with mina_sidekiq.
When I trace the deploy I can see:

```
-----> Start sidekiq
       $ bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production -C /root/sites/mina_deploy/current/config/sidekiq.yml -i 0 -P /root/sites/mina_deploy/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid -L /root/sites/mina_deploy/current/log/sidekiq.log
```

So this SHOULD get my config file that has the queues in it:

```
---
:queues:
  - default
  - [mailer, 10]
```

But then when I run sidekiq webview, I can only see the default queue.
In localhost it works fine

My mina deploy file has the following:

```
...
require 'mina_sidekiq/tasks'

task setup: :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  # sidekiq needs a place to store its pid file and log file
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/pids/"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/pids"]

  ...
end

task deploy: :environment do
  deploy do
    invoke :'sidekiq:quiet'
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    to :launch do
      queue "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/"
      queue "touch #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"

      invoke :'sidekiq:restart'
      invoke :'puma:restart'

    end
  end
end
```

Why can't I get the right queues??

Answer (score 1):

After pulling lots of hair, I tried running sidekiq on the server and it failed to start because of the Redis version. There is was no warning, so it was not possible to trace. Updating to a later version of Redis and deploying with mina again got it all rolling.
I have to thank Jörg Thalheim for brainstorming with me looking for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Queues don't show up in the web UI until you actually push a job to them.

Comment: Mike, I did push a job... many. They all go under "default", but they do go under the correct one on development. Also, I can confirm that my pid is created by the mina deploy just fine on the server, but when I do mina sidekiq:stop it gives me "skip stopping sidekiq (no pid file found)". Also, I know the config file exists. I can cat/nano into it. Any other ideas?